# Why is this python code not working?

Tags: python, list, file, loops, csv

I am trying to add 1 to score every time the user gets an answer right, you can see I am getting the questions and answers from a file, and the file is set up to have the question first, followed by the possible answers, then followed by the correct answer.

> Example: What is 2 * 2?,4,2,8,6,a

That would be what is in the file that I am reading. Every time I run it, it will go through fine with all the loops and lists and stuff, but it will not add 1 to the score every time it is the correct answer. Anyone see a problem with this part of code?

```
inputtedAnswer = input("Choice (a-d): ")

if inputtedAnswer == rightAnswer[0]:
    score += 1
else:
    score = score
```

Comment: rightAnswer[0] is where i stored the information in list form for the correct answer but it will not recgonize when i compare it to a string..

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you sure that rightAnswer and inputtedAnswer are what you expect them to be? My guess would be you either need to cast rightAnswer[0] as a string(`str(rightAnswer[0])`)  or that something doesn't have the value you think it has.

Comment: Inspect the values with ```print(inputtedAnswer, rightAnswer[0])```. Are they equal? Are they the same type? are they what you expected them to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your rightAnswer list, it is difficult to know what the problem is. I created a list called rightAnswer and set the 0 index to equal 1 as an integer. I then used your code to check what the user typed in. The only difference was that I converted the input to an integer because rightAnswer[0] was an integer. Note that converting input to an integer is not a good idea because the program will crash if the user types in a string. After that, your program worked fine.

```
rightAnswer = [1]
score = 0

inputtedAnswer = int(input("Type in 1"))

if inputtedAnswer == rightAnswer[0]:
    score += 1
    print ("Score: " + score)
else:
    score = score
```

I think that that is what you wanted but it is difficult to know without knowing the contents of your rightAnswer list

Comment: thanks! totally forgot about the int vs. string.. im new to python, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help